# Multiple fields with Twitter's Bootstrap typehead inside a modal

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal with a form and two input fields that make use of bootstrap's typeahead.
Both are working, but the results of the second one are not displayed correctly as you can see below:

[image]

Can someone help me on this one?

**EDIT**

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function(){

    var stopObjs = {};
    var stopNamen = [];

    $(".naamtypeahead").typeahead({
        source: function ( query, process ) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '../includes/js/autocompletenaam.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'naam=' + query
                ,cache: false
                ,success: function(data){

                    stopObjs = {
                    };
                    stopNamen = [];

                    _.each( data, function(item, ix, list){

                        stopNamen.push( item.naam )

                        stopObjs[ item.naam ] = item.adres;
                    });

                        process( stopNamen );
                }
            });
        }
        , updater: function ( adres) {

            $( ".adres" ).val( stopObjs[ adres ] );

            return adres;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: perhaps conflicting css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the same problem (looks like some kind of a bug, see: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/8436 for a possible fix). The menu with options gets a css top with position absolute. When using the typeahead in a modal the scroll height is not used in the calculation of the top. This issue has been fixed in: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

The scrolling of the modal cause the problem not the use of multiple fields (with typeahead).

**The best solution i found (update!)**:

```
function scrollHeight()
{
  return $('.modal-body').scrollTop();
} 

$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
      var pos = $.extend({}, this.$element.position(), {
        height: this.$element[0].offsetHeight
      })

      this.$menu
        .insertAfter(this.$element)
        .css({
          top: (pos.top + pos.height + scrollHeight.call())
        , left: pos.left
        })
        .show()

      this.shown = true
      return this

    }
```

This will overwrite the show function of the typeahead class <strike>and adds `+ $('.modal-body').scrollTop()` to it.</strike> and adds a call to scrollHeight to set the height dynamic.

See also **update** : http://bootply.com/66845 (remove the javascript to see the problem)

**update 20 aug**

The code above only works with one modal (only one .modal-body class). For two or more modals use the code below:

```
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
      var pos = $.extend({}, this.$element.position(), {
        height: this.$element[0].offsetHeight
      })                    
      this.$menu
        .insertAfter(this.$element)
        .css({
          top: (pos.top + pos.height + this.$element.closest('.modal-body').scrollTop())
        , left: pos.left
        })
        .show()

      this.shown = true
      return this

}
```

## Twitter's Typeahead and Twitter's Bootstrap 3

Twitter's Bootstrap 3 drops bootstrap-typeahead.js and tells to use Twitter's Typeahead (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). See also: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7805. Switching to Twitter's Typeahead (with Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x) also seems to fix your problem. **But ...**
To use Twitter's Typeahead  with Bootstrap you need to add some extra stylesheet: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#bootstrap-integration.
When using this in a modal with multiple (typeahead) form fields the form fields will be over the dropdown menu. To fix this add a z-index:1 to your stylesheet:

```
.twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  margin-bottom: 0;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

See also: https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/pull/13

### Twitter's Bootstrap 3

The Bootstrap integration of Twitter's Typeahead for Twitter's Bootstrap 3 don't work well at the moment (10 july 2013)

Comment: To bad.. Twitters Typeahead looks nice. I've also tried your first solution. Still without success though.

Comment: yes, i made a mistake for solution 1. I should work now see update and try http://bootply.com/66845 (updated too)

Comment: Yes, I can see some difference, I can scroll now without causing the typeahead results disappear, but still the results are not shown in the right place somehow..

Comment: the bootply works for you? Could you post your html or make a bootply with your code?

Comment: In your bootply things are looking as they should.

Comment: First, my apology for such a long time no response.. The past few days I had the chance to get back to this problem again. And your last solution is working absolutely fine, BUT, when I use 2 buttons with 2 different modals, only the first loaded modal is working fine. The second one still shows the problem like before, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jk22/TL5cT/3/ Do you have any tips or ideas to take this last obstacle?

Comment: np. Yes the problem is you will have two .modal-body classes now. See the update of my answer. You don't need the scrollHeight function with this latest fix.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much for all your effort and patience!

Answer (score 1):

I've found this problem, too. I've correct by using this code:-

top: (pos.top + pos.height + this.$element.offsetParent().scrollTop())

so this should correct position on all scrolling div, which typeAhead be inside it.